# Java search list of objects for variable

Tags: java, list

I have a List of Book

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

public class Book {
    String name;
    List<Author> authors;
}
```

Book contains a List of Author which contains an ID, Name and Age

```
public class Author {
    int ID;
    String Name;
    int Age;
}
```

I can iterate through the books List and return the `Book` where Name = x but I'm not sure how I can search `Author` and return where Name = y.

Comment: Why are you using Authors in an ArrayList ? Are there multiple Authors for every single book ?

Comment: Multiple authors for some books would be reason enough to use an arraylist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a method `hasAuthor(String)` to your `Book` which loops through the `List<Author>` list and compares the name. Like so:

```
boolean hasAuthor(String name) {
    for (Author author : authors) {
        if (author.name.equals(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To find books with a specific author, you loop over the `List<Book>` and invoke the `hasAuthor(String)` method.

Comment: +1 I like this over iterating outside the `Book` class as it is more cleaner.

Comment: Or, you could avoid using a for loop if you override the `equals(Object)` method in your `Author` class.

Comment: I missed this from the original post. I'm wanting to check all the Authors for Name = x, regardless of what book they wrote. If I did it this way surely I'd have to iterate through each book and then run the author search iteration for each?

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this method. I have about 4k Books and Authors so thought it might be slow iterating twice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is off topic, but when solving such problems, having *objects with nested lists*, though logically simple, is a really *bad* idea. Its extremely hard to maintain, scale and work with.

If you use this structure throughout and come across a problem like:

***Give me all the books written by this author.***

You are toast, you will have to iterate over each and every book. Or start maintaining caches and what not. It gets worse when the nesting deepens.

Lets say, now you need to maintain each Author's list of hobbies too. Think of how would you implement something like : **Give me all the books whose authors like *skydiving*!**

I know this doesn't answer your question. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The real data I'm using does go 3 levels deep and does seem like a pain to work this. Unfortunately I'm deserializing someone else's data that I have no control over so I think it would be even more of a pain to try and change the objects on my side. But that's probably for another thread.

Comment: @rocketboy - conceptually, I agree with you.  Q: How *would* you design a "searchable collection of books"?

Comment: @rocketboy, what do you recommend then in the type of situations where you to answer questions like "give me all the books written by this author". I have a similar type of problem at the moment and searching for a better way than next a list inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

Something primitive:

```
List<Author> authors;
...
Iterator<Author> ai = authors.iterator();
Author a;
while(ai.hasNext()){
    a = ai.next();
    if(a.name.equalsIgnoreCase(yourname)){
       return a;
    }
    continue;
}
```

Edit: Too late :/